# Using Scala Play WS to follow links in downloaded resources

Tags: java, scala, rest, hateoas

I am using an API in HATEOAS style, which contains links to other resources embedded in the response from the server, as in

```
{
  "lat": 51.50559,
  "lon": 7.31667,
  "id": "85a02d3c-b501-4429-a944-b2fd578688cb",
  "_links": {
    "soundings": {
      "href": "/locations/85a02d3c-b501-4429-a944-b2fd578688cb/soundings"
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "https://some.server/locations/85a02d3c-b501-4429-a944-b2fd578688cb"
    }
  }
}
```

I am using the Play framework with Scala (www.playframework.com), and the `WSClient` of that framework to call the API. As you can see, in this response the links are sometimes relative, and sometimes absolute (when the resource is available on another server). In the end, I'd like to follow the embedded links.

I'd like to avoid manually fiddling with the host/protocol and sometimes relative/sometimes absolute URLs to get an absolute URL which I can feed to the `WSClient`. In the end, I am looking for some tool that behaves "like a web browser" when dealing with absolute and relative URLs.

Is there a possibility to give this task to the `WSClient` of the play framework or the underlying akka-http? If not, which other REST client can you suggest that can do the job (preferably Scala; Java would work, too)?

Comment: No. I don' think it can be done that way.

Comment: So, I can think of writing something to achieve that, I just wonder if nobody did something like that before. Seems a natural thing to me to want.